# I accidentally put my 2D colliders on the Main Camera and not my Maze Sprite

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, pacman

I am currently following a tutorial to make Pacman in Unity. I was told to use 2d colliders around the little blocks that Pacman goes around. I've accidentally put the colliders on the main camera and not the maze sprite.

Will this affect my game in any way? Or do I need to put the colliders on the sprite? If I do is there any quick way to redo my colliders?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the link to the tutorial: https://noobtuts.com/unity/2d-pacman-game

I am happy to provide screenshots if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will still need to add a collider to the maze sprite so the player can collide with it.

If you accidentally put a collider on your camera, you can right-click on the top of the component and click remove.

[image]

Comment: Ah okay thank you. Is there any simple way to move all of my colliders from the main camera to the sprite or do I have to do them all over?

Comment: You can also click on the "Copy Component" button and right-click on one of your components on the maze and click "Paste component as new"